# Why is saving a single entity to my EF Core database context resulting in multiple inserts?

Tags: c#, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I am simply building a model and then attempting to insert it to the database via the `.SaveChanges()` function, but when I run `SaveChanges()` I get a database error that a primary key duplicate has occurred...

so I dug into the SQL logging and found that this model insert is attempting to re-insert already existing data... why would that happen?

**My code**

```
using (var dbContext = new dbContext(_dbContextOptions))
{
    Request request = new Request()
    {
       RequesterId = 1,
       HelpRequestType = helpRequestTypeObject, //new model is being inserted for this on .SaveChanges()
       Status = statusObject, //new model is being inserted for this on .SaveChanges()
       AssignmentKeyId = 12, 
       TimeCreated = DateTime.Now,
       CustomContactIds = null
    };

    //add request to transaction
    dbContext.Request.Add(request);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

EDIT: So I changed everything to create the model only using ids for foreign key references (no directly linked entities) and this seems to have solved my issue.  Once the entity is created and .SaveChanges() has been applied, the model has links to all other entities as expected.  It seems I was causing myself problems by using entities that had been previously queried under a different DbContext than the active one I was using for this new entity creation.

Comment: What is the primary key of your model?

Comment: @Michael Randall, my stupid employer's locked down browser doesn't support Stack Overflow... So I had to post that from mobile... Apologies for the lack of tabs... It was copied from an email and didn't retain formatting

Comment: @Sami , the primary key is auto-generated in the database so it doesn't need to be included on the model

Comment: Could you include the definition of your `Request` model?

Comment: It is happening because you did not define a primary key on your "Request" entity class. You need [Key] annotation ontop of the field used as the key, in your C# class.

Comment: @eerick Please post the `Request` model class, it's model definition (FluentApi) and the `CREATE TABLE` script of the `Request` MySQL table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But it appears the issue was that I was directly linking existing entity models to the new model instead of linking them by ID...
>
> I was querying for existing entities from the database and linking them to this new Request object directly rather than just by ID... This resulted in Entity Framework attempting to remake all the existing entities...

When you are using entities from more then one `DbContext`, you need to be careful. If you query a `HelpRequestType` object from `contextA`, and connect it to an object belonging to `contextB`, then `contextB` has not been tracking the `HelpRequestType` object and has no way of knowing, that the object is already part of the underlying database. It therefore considers the object as new. This is even true, if both contexts are of the same derived type.

If you need to use two different `DbContext` objects for some reason, you need to [Attach()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.attach?view=efcore-3.1) the `HelpRequestType` object of `contextA` to `contextB` first, before calling `SaveChanges()` on `contextB`.

Generally, it is way easier to just work with a single `DbContext` object for all operations (unit of work pattern). You should have a good reason (performance, a model that is partitioned over multiple data stores, etc.) for using more then one `DbContext`.

See also [Working with Disconnected Entity Graph in Entity Framework Core](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/working-with-disconnected-entity-graph-ef-core.aspx) for further details.

Comment: to make sure I am following this correctly, you are saying the reason new data is being inserted to the database by EF is because I had not attached them to the current DbContext?  So if I query entities on a context and then use them on the same context, my problem described above would not occur? but in this case it did because I used two different contexts? (one for the initial query and a separate one for this model creation)

Comment: the reason I am using two different contexts is because this is a library method expecting the models to be passed in (so they have already been queried by another method in another application)... so it seems the Attach() method as you described is the best way to solve my dilemma

Comment: @eerick That is correct. The two `DbContext` instances are the problem, because they don't track each others objects. But you can attach any object to a context, by calling `Attach()`. In case of your library, you can either just use `Attach()` and work with your own context, or you can let the user specify his own context instance together with the object.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not exactly sure why it was the issue, as I thought I had seen this done elsewhere... But it appears the issue was that I was directly linking existing entity models to the new model instead of linking them by ID...

I was querying for existing entities from the database and linking them to this new Request object directly rather than just by ID... This resulted in Entity Framework attempting to remake all the existing entities...

I changed the places I was using models instead of IDs and it all appears to be working now.